# How to modify title text and keep auto numbering - VBA, word

Tags: vba, ms-word

In MS Word (2010 .docx) file I need to modify text of title with **autonumber**, but keep the **autonumber**:

Original Word Example:

*1.4.12 [ORIGINAL_TEXT]*

Intended tile after modification:

*1.4.12 [MODIFIED_TEXT]*

I can get the [ORIGINAL_TEXT] by

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text
```

This returns [ORIGINAL_TEXT], but not autonumber.

But by setting

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text = "[MODIFIED_TEXT]"
```

the autonumber disappear and the title text is only

*[MODIFIED_TEXT]*

(autonumber missing)

From there I understand, that assigning anything to *ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text* is not a way, because I want to keep autonumber.

I was able to modify the title by

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.InsertBefore ("[MODIFIED_TEXT]")
```

This results in title in form:

*1.4.12 [MODIFIED_TEXT][ORIGINAL_TEXT]*

(This looks like pointless, but actually my [ORIGINAL_TEXT] is constant text in whole document - it is placeholder, which tells mactro where to insert autogenerated text "[MODIFIED_TEXT]". Therefore after inserting autogenerated text by *InsertBefore* I can later simply do find and replace "[ORIGINAL_text]" to "", but I want to avoid this second step)

How it is possible to replace [ORIGINAL_TEXT] by [MODIFIED_TEXT] without loosing the **autonumber**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text` includes the paragraph mark (carriage return).

To replace the text you can either include a carriage return in your replacement text

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text = "[MODIFIED_TEXT]" & vbCr
```

or modify the range you are replacing

```
  Dim textRange As Range
  Set textRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range
  textRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
  textRange.text = "Modified text"
```

Comment: Thank you Timothy. The first example (& vbCr) didn't work for me, but the second worked well.

Answer (score 0):

The autonumber is likely in the paragraph formatting so you would want to avoid replacing the paragraph mark unless you can add that formatting back.